# VBA code or macro copying cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have no experience with macro/vba.

[image: picture]

As you can see all column A has PINK TEAM label but different category (tennis, swimming, volleyball). In my spreadsheet, there are a lot of PINK TEAM label all the way down but different category (tennis, swimming, etc). I want to be able to add name, say for example add Remy to Pink Team Tennis and all cell with PINK TEAM / Tennis should be able to automatically add REMY on column C.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show us what you have tried so far. Phrases like *urgent* are somewhat frowned on. Everything here is urgent, so to say.

Comment: You want someone to write the code from scratch?

Comment: yes please thank you so much

Comment: hi yacc.. sorry to sound a bit hopeless..lol..but i really am..i havent tried writing any code so far but I have spent quite some time researching..there are codes which i think will give the same result however i find it hard understanding how to change the value of that example to my actual value..

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a code writing service!  We are here to help programmers with problems they are having in code they have actually written.  If you want someone to write code you are going to have to pay someone to do it.

Comment: really appreciate if someone can help me with this..or is IF and VLOOKUP function enough for this to work??

Comment: i do understand that..i just do not know how it works at all and based from all the researches that i did, it seems VBA and macro code are the only options..anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: Try setting up a table with Sports in a column and team member names in adjacent columns for each team color.  Then use the `MATCH` function to get the position of the sport in the list and return the `INDEX` from the team color column.

Comment: hi mark..the spreadsheet is already done as it is...actually i just sort of used another details but my goal is still teh same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub AddName()
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long, count As Long
    Dim Team As String, Sport As String, NewPlayer As String

    Team = "Pink Team"
    Sport = InputBox("What Sport do you wish to add a name to?", "Sport")
    NewPlayer = InputBox("What is the name of the player you wish to add?", "New Player")
        With ActiveSheet
            lr = .Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 1 To lr
                If .Range("A" & i).Value = Team And .Range("B" & i).Value = Sport Then
                    .Range("C" & i).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value & ", " & NewPlayer
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    If count = 0 Then MsgBox "The " & Team & " doesnt appear to play " & Sport & " yet."
End Sub
```

To add the code hit `ALT + F11` on your keyboard. Then double click the sheet name (top left) you wish to add the code to & paste the code there.

Comment: Thank you so much calico!!you are a life saver!